# Algolia cannot resolve host

Tags: php, api, laravel, algolia

i have just created a user for Algolia. But when i try to connect trough the API, i receive an error message with "Cannot resolve host" and it try's all the different Algolia hosts. i have used the guide on their site and tried to connect both trough vanilla PHP and trough Laravel.

I saw another guy with this problem(Algolia Rails), he said to wait a couple of hours, and i have waited 5+ hours at this time.. still no solution like he got.

What could it be, and should i just keep waiting? Or is there a problem on Algolia's end?

Comment: How are you running your Laravel app?

Comment: I just needed to wait a bit more. Now it got through. Just wait it; will work after a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

There is normally no delay to begin using your new account.

However Algolia has had an issue concerning the DNS records creation for new accounts... hence the unusual long delay!

The issue is now resolved :)